# Image source not working in cakePHP

Tags: php, image, cakephp, src

I'm trying to figure out how to make my image source show inside my image using cakephp. Whenever I try to put the source using `$this->Html` it only shows a blank text.

This is how I call my image:

```
<img class="banner-image" src="<?php $this->Html->image('theme/banner.png', array('alt' => 'CakePHP', 'border' => '0')); ?>" />
```

and this is how it shows in the

```
<img class="banner-image" src="" />
```

what seems to be the problem?

Comment: Please check the docs first: **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::image**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 echo $this->Html->image('theme/banner.png', array('class' => 'banner-image'));
```

Answer (score 4):

maybe **theme/banner.png** don't exist in app/webroot? Try this code with URL link.

```
echo $this->Html->image("theme/banner.png", 
    array("alt" => "CakePHP",'url' => array('controller' => 'Student', 'action' => 'view', 6)
));
```